# Can somebody explain the following syntax in this C++ code

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

```
 string swapLettersUpdated(string s, char c1, char c2) {
   transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), [&c1, &c2](char c) {
        return c == c1 ? c2 : c == c2 ? c1 : c;
        });

    return s;
}
```

I have problems understanding the [&c1, &c2](char c) part and the part after return.
It is a function that swaps letters.

Comment: That's a lambda capture and parameter list: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: the dupe is for lambdas, after the return is the conditional operator https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other